# Call javascript function residing in iframe from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have one html openning inside an iframe.One javaScript function is defined there say getSomething().Now in the parent page I have one external javaScript file.Is it possible for me to access getSomething() from the external javaScript file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call javascript function from outside an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140696/call-javascript-function-from-outside-an-iframe).  Please do not re-ask the same question if you don't get a suitable answer to the first.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both URLs are from the same domain, you can do it. Try calling something similar to the following from the external script file:

```
document.getElementByID("ReferringiFrame").getSomething();
```

Comment: I saw Andy E's comment on your question. Seems like it might be a duplicate question. Please check the suggested answers there first...